# How can I use isSucces multiple times to check data has come or not? Hook return isSuccess to check data has come or not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, react-hooks, react-redux

[image: 1]

I wanted to get isSuccess value for each hook!

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your question properly, however I assume the below.

- There is a state isSuccess which will be updated to true, whenever data is received.
- You want to do something when isSuccess becomes true.

So, here you can use the hook, useEffect having the dependency on isSuccess, like below.

```
useEffect(()=>{
if(isSuccess === true){
//set of code to do something on change of isSuccess
}
},[isSuccess])
```

Also inside the component if you want to render something only when isSuccess is true then you can add like below.

```
<>
{isSuccess && <div> this displays only when isSuccess is true!! </div> }
</>
```

Let me know if I have misunderstood, if I need to clarify something else